# copy file in PHP

Tags: php, copy

I'm trying to copy some images from a public website with the [PHP function copy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php), but this function take too much time, and sometimes I get `Maximum execution time Fatal error`. I've increased the maximum script running time to 3minutes, but I still get that error sometimes.

I'm curious to know if is there another better/smarter solution for copying/downloading files.

Comment: Please show some more details. What are you copying from where? Maybe show some cource code

Comment: Do you have curl -  why not grab the images with curl?  Are you respecting the owners copyright?

Comment: Is it failing because each individual file takes longer than 3 minutes, or because the entire script looping over files is taking longer than 3 minutes?

Comment: @David: the line with copy is giving me the error code

Comment: @dole: As others have suggested, curl could help you.  Maybe even use PHP to just spawn off a wget process?  I don't know much about threading in PHP, but I imagine you could spawn a bunch of them and let them do their thing while the script just happily idles.

Comment: @Shaun Hare: I copy some covers books from a website similar with amazon in my db, but for my own collection/digital library. I'm not allowed to do that?

Comment: @dole, I would advise checking the site's copyright policy or checking with the site to be on the safe side. I am not best placed to answer the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using curl:
http://www.google.com.br/search?q=curl+php+download+image

Comment: Downvoter, please tell me why the answer was downvoted, so i can give a better answer next time.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but if I were to guess I would say it might be that linking to Google searches is a carefully-crafted thing in most SO answers.  It's better to link to something more substantial.  Google searches help in some context, but the standard "let me Google that for you" answer is frowned upon, and this comes close to that.  (Also, this Google link is culture-specific.)

Comment: ty. I didn't know about curl. I have no idea for the downvote. Can we find out who did it in order to know his reasons?

Comment: @dole: Not unless the downvoter makes himself known.  Voting is anonymous here.